# Defending your mistakes abruptly

Tags: meaning, phrases, synonyms

I see some people make mistakes in conversation then they counter-attack you if you point out their mistakes. Let's take an example:

> Jay: I don't like Chinese food because I hate china.
>   Xu(Chinese Guy): How can you say these things about Chinese.
>   Jay(Careful manner): I was talking about specific people. You are my brother how can you even think it was against you, I am ashamed.

So Jay did the mistake and he is trying to defend by diverting the topic. Do we have any specific word or slang for such type of act or behavior of Jay?

Comment: Backing off...?

Comment: I found one idiom "Pot calling the kettle black". It is similar but is not same

Comment: The example provided doesn't seem like much of an "attack", which I think in the context of an argument implies saying negative things about the opponent more than it implies changing the subject.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for dismissing someone's opinions as racist, liberal, etc, instead of debating back](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256517/word-for-dismissing-someones-opinions-as-racist-liberal-etc-instead-of-debat) contains 'An ad hominem ,short for argumentum ad hominem, means responding to arguments by attacking a person's character, rather than to the content of their arguments. ... a fallacy in which a claim or argument is dismissed on the basis of some irrelevant fact or supposition about the author or the person being criticized.'

Answer (score 0):

**Evasive** (Source: [Cambridge Dicitonary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/evasive))

> answering questions in a way that is not direct or clear, especially because you do not want to give an honest answer:
>
> done to avoid something bad happening:

**Dodge**

> to avoid something unpleasant:
> a clever, dishonest way of avoiding something:

`Example`: Jay is being *evasive* by *dodging* the confrontation.